# PostgreSQL Update a row of a table

Tags: php, html, sql, database, postgresql

Variables:

```
 $Dream =($_POST['Dream']);
 $Price =($_POST['Price']);
 $Delivery =($_POST['Delivery']);
```

PostgreSQL:

```
 $result = pg_query($conn, "UPDATE dream SET name = '$Dream', price = '$Price', 
 delivery = '$Delivery' FROM (SELECT imageID, name, price, delivery) WHERE 
 imageID=1");
```

**I want to update the row where imageID is 1.** 
Thank you in advance if anyone can point out where i'm going wrong. 
The current code does not run and ends with a HTTP error 500.

Comment: Learn to use parameters so you are not munging query strings with literal values.

Comment: Thank you, in this specific case though with what i'm working with they need to be literal values.

Comment: . . There is never a *need* to use literal values for constants in a query.  There are issues if you are replacing identifiers, or functions, or operators.  But constant values can always use parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $result = pg_query($conn, "UPDATE dream SET name = '$Dream', price = '$Price', 
 delivery = '$Delivery' WHERE  imageID=1");
```

You do not need the `FROM (SELECT imageID, name, price, delivery)` part

You can try:

```
 $result = pg_query($conn, "UPDATE dream SET name = '".$Dream."', price = '".$Price."', delivery = '".$Delivery."' WHERE  imageID=1");
```

Comment: Thank you, I removed that, it still isnt running though. Is there anything glaring obvious mistakes you can see?

Comment: edited my answer with a suggestion. Not that proficient in php though, and my initial answer should work with php and mysql, but I guess postgres is a bit more pretentious :). If that fails I would suggest trying to use https://www.phptutorial.info/?pg-query-params. Also replace your query with a simple select to rule out that there aren't any issues with other parts of your code that could be responsible for the 500 error

Comment: Thank you for the help, it accepted that, pretentious indeed. Thanks again!